# Cythonize two small numpy functions, help needed

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cython, memoryview

## The problem

I'm trying to Cythonize two small functions that mostly deal with numpy ndarrays for some scientific purpose. These two smalls functions are called millions of times in a genetic algorithm and account for the majority of the time taken by the algo.

I made some progress on my own and both work nicely, but i get only a tiny speed improvement (10%). More importantly, cython --annotate show that the majority of the code is still going through Python.

## The code

### First function:

The aim of this function is to get back slices of data and it is called millions of times in an inner nested loop. Depending on the bool in data[1][1], we either get the slice in the forward or reverse order.

```
#Ipython notebook magic for cython
%%cython --annotate
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal as scisignal

cimport cython
cimport numpy as np
def get_signal(data):
    #data[0] contains the data structure containing the numpy arrays
    #data[1][0] contains the position to slice
    #data[1][1] contains the orientation to slice, forward = 0, reverse = 1

    cdef int halfwinwidth = 100
    cdef int midpoint = data[1][0]
    cdef int strand = data[1][1]
    cdef int start = midpoint - halfwinwidth
    cdef int end = midpoint + halfwinwidth
    #the arrays we want to slice
    cdef np.ndarray r0 = data[0]['normals_forward']
    cdef np.ndarray r1 = data[0]['normals_reverse']
    cdef np.ndarray r2 = data[0]['normals_combined']
    if strand == 0:
        normals_forward = r0[start:end]
        normals_reverse = r1[start:end]
        normals_combined = r2[start:end]
    else:
        normals_forward = r1[end - 1:start - 1: -1]
        normals_reverse = r0[end - 1:start - 1: -1]
        normals_combined = r2[end - 1:start - 1: -1]
    #return the result as a tuple
    row = (normals_forward,
           normals_reverse,
           normals_combined)
    return row
```

### Second function

This one gets a list of tuples of numpy arrays, and we want to add up the arrays element wise, then normalize them and get the integration of the intersection.

```
def calculate_signal(list signal):
    cdef int halfwinwidth = 100
    cdef np.ndarray profile_normals_forward = np.zeros(halfwinwidth * 2, dtype='f')
    cdef np.ndarray profile_normals_reverse = np.zeros(halfwinwidth * 2, dtype='f')
    cdef np.ndarray profile_normals_combined = np.zeros(halfwinwidth * 2, dtype='f')
    #b is a tuple of 3 np.ndarrays containing 200 floats
    #here we add them up elementwise
    for b in signal:
        profile_normals_forward += b[0]
        profile_normals_reverse += b[1]
        profile_normals_combined += b[2]
    #normalize the arrays
    cdef int count = len(signal)

    #print "Normalizing to number of elements"
    profile_normals_forward /= count
    profile_normals_reverse /= count
    profile_normals_combined /= count
    intersection_signal = scisignal.detrend(np.fmin(profile_normals_forward, profile_normals_reverse))
    intersection_signal[intersection_signal < 0] = 0
    intersection = np.sum(intersection_signal)

    results = {"intersection": intersection,
               "profile_normals_forward": profile_normals_forward,
               "profile_normals_reverse": profile_normals_reverse,
               "profile_normals_combined": profile_normals_combined,
               }
    return results
```

Any help is appreciated - I tried using memory views but for some reason the code got much, much slower.

Comment: `cdef np.ndarray` doesn't give a huge speedup. You have to specify the `dtype` to get a real boost. (That syntax is deprecated, though.)

Comment: if function 1 is called millions of times you should use `cdef` for this function and put the routine which is calling this function inside Cython as well... another issue may be that `data` is a dictionary, I am not sure if this is the best way to get a real improvement. Perhaps you should use a `ndarray` for `data`

Comment: Is the new syntax typed memoryviews? Cause i tried doing cdef float [:] as a type instead and the performance got 300% worse for some reason

Comment: Specify types, and use C types instead of Python types.  BTW, numba might be good too.

Comment: This might be a great time to point out [numba](http://numba.pydata.org). Numba is a JIT compiler for python/numpy and in my tests the automatic compilation feature is roughly on par with optimized cython.

Comment: i tried numba but no matter what function i try to @autojit, it gives me NULL result without error in PyObject_Call and doesn't run

Comment: Installing numba as a standalone package can be kind of tricky. If very basic examples do not work try grabbing a binary installation of python/numba/otherstuff from [continuum](http://continuum.io/downloads).

Comment: I got the anaconda distribution so its straight from there

Comment: Typing the argument float [:] only makes sense when the calling function is also a Cython function that also has the array cdef'ed to that type. Otherwise you're creating a new memory view with every invocation.

Answer (score 0):

After fixing the array cdef (as has been indicated, with the dtype specified), you should probably put the routine in a cdef function (which will only be callable by a def function in the same script).

In the declaration of the function, you'll need to provide the type (and the dimensions if it's an array numpy):

```
cdef get_signal(numpy.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=3] data):
```

I'm not sure using a dict is a good idea though. You could make use of numpy's column or row slices like data[:, 0].